# Manipulating a column based on other column values with R dplyr package

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, dplyr

I would like to choose best 2 results of quiz exams (highest score and highest attendance) for each student and eliminate the weakest quiz over 3 quiz exams. We might say that I would like to choose best 2 columns from 3 columns for each row. Then create a new data frame has `StudentID, ExamQuiz1, ExamQuiz2, ExamMidterm and ExamFinal`. I can handle it with looping through the table which is too inefficient in R I assume that. What is the efficient way to handle the issue with dplyr package?

**Minimalist data**

The pseudo data frame is placed at the bottom. "`G`" means the student has not attended the exam so I would like to keep that value instead of replacing it into the 0. For instance, if he got this scenario with G (`ExamQuiz1`), 0 (`ExamQuiz2`), 10 (`ExamQuiz3`), I have to choose 0 as `ExamQuiz1` and 10 as `ExamQuiz2` for quiz inputs. Because 0 is better than `G` because of attendance side. If there is a result (with numbers), it means that student has already attended. Every single cell under the columns of `ExamQuiz1, ExamQuiz2, ExamMidterm and ExamFinal` might have numeric (exam result) or character value ("`G`" > not attended). I will not touch any values of ExamMidterm and ExamFinal columns. The main idea is only related with the columns of `ExamQuiz1, ExamQuiz2, and ExamQuiz3`.

```
   StudentID  ExamQuiz1  ExamQuiz2  ExamQuiz3  ExamMidterm  ExamFinal
1      11111          0          G          G            G          G
2      22222          0          G         43           71         18
3      33333          0          G          G            G          G
4      44444          0          G          G            G          G
5      55555         60         38          G           64         27
6      66666          0          G          G            G          G
```

**Edit**: Still some of commenters constantly point that the data is not tidy. As I explained on the comments, the reason for that or what you are offering to tidy it up do not make sense on my side. For that reason, I placed more explanations on the question body without changing the structure of the data.

Comment: What does highest attendance mean? Each student was either at the quiz or not, so how can there be a highest attendance for each student?  Your data is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Whilst that doesn't matter much for a toy example like this, making all your data tidy is a good habit to have.  It will save you time in the long run!

Comment: @Limey If you read carefully, you will see that "G" means the student has not attended. For that reason, if he got this scenario with 10, G, 0, I have to choose 10 and 0 as quiz inputs. Because 0 is better than G because of attendance side. If there is a result (with numbers), it means that student has already attended. It is pretty simple and the data is purely tidy!

Comment: "The data is purely tidy".  I beg to disagree: you have information in your column names.  Good luck with finding a solution.

Comment: Hi @ozturkib, patronizing people trying to help you in the comments is unlikely to result in your question being answered.

Comment: @Limey Why the data is not tidy in your opinion?

Comment: @IanCampbell I am not patronising anybody at all. I am just explaining every single details and not accepting that comment with the given reasons. That is all.

Comment: In your real data are their likely to be "G"s in every column?  I ask because they will make the "type" of the column character not numeric

Comment: @ChuckP Thanks for the comment. Yes it is absolutely right. It is not numeric and it has to be character. For that reason, I am using stringsAsFactors=FALSE in order to read the data from file. However, this is off-topic but for the reason of your question, I gave more details about this side.

Comment: @ChuckP For the clarification, every single column might have numeric (exam result) or  character value ("G" > not attended).

Comment: @ozturkib:  I acccept that in some situations, "tidyness" can be open to interpretation.  But here, I think the situation is clear.  From the link I quoted above, one of the conditions for tidyness is "each variable forms a column".  Here, your variable of interest is "quiz score" - because that is the value you wish to summarise.  But quiz score is stored in 3 columns.  (5 if `midterm` and `final` are also quizzes.)  In my opinion, in your context, one way of making your data tidy would be to have columns ID, Time and Score.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I have just started to work and realised that the question is closed because of lack of information based on feedback! I am really shocked because I am always careful once I am writing a question on stackoverflow. For that reason, I firstly focused on the reason of closing the question. Later on, I will move on trying below answers. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R solution

```
cbind(df[-(2:4)], t(apply(df[2:4], 1, function(x){
  c(x[x == "G"], sort(x[x != "G"]))[-1]
})))

#   StudentID Midterm Final  1  2
# 1     11111       G     G  G  0
# 2     22222      71    18  0 43
# 3     33333       G     G  G  0
# 4     44444       G     G  G  0
# 5     55555      64    27 38 60
# 6     66666       G     G  G  0
```

In your rule, `G` should be put in front of any numerics. So at first I put all existing `G` to the beginning of a vector and append sorted scores. After removing the first element in the vector, top 2 scores will remain.

Comment: Yes, it is solved but i need to keep try it in the following week. Then, i will mark it as an answer, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`'s new `across` (version `1.0.0` or higher):

Assuming no one can get a negative score and being absent is worse than getting zero, we can just set `G` to be `-1`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(across(-StudentID, ~case_when(. == "G" ~ -1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(.)))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TopQuiz = max(c_across(starts_with("Quiz"))),
         SecondQuiz = sort(c_across(starts_with("Quiz")),
                           decreasing = TRUE)[2]) %>%
  dplyr::select(StudentID, TopQuiz, SecondQuiz, Midterm, Final) %>%
  mutate(across(-StudentID, ~case_when(. == -1 ~ "G",
                                       TRUE ~ as.character(.))))
##A tibble: 6 x 5
## Rowwise: 
#  StudentID TopQuiz SecondQuiz Midterm Final
#      <int> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>
#1     11111 0       G          G       G    
#2     22222 43      0          71      18   
#3     33333 0       G          G       G    
#4     44444 0       G          G       G    
#5     55555 60      38         64      27   
#6     66666 0       G          G       G
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way of applying `dplyr` and `stringr` by making G NA to do the math and then putting NA back to G and returning to character.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


newgrades <- grades %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Quiz"), ~ str_replace(., "G", NA_character_))) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Quiz"), as.numeric)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TopQuiz = max(c_across(starts_with("Quiz")), na.rm = TRUE),
         NextBestQuiz = sort(c_across(starts_with("Quiz")),
                             decreasing = TRUE)[2]) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("Quiz"), as.character)) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("Quiz"), ~ str_replace_na(., replacement = "G"))) %>%
  select(id, TopQuiz, NextBestQuiz, Midterm, Final)

newgrades
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id TopQuiz NextBestQuiz Midterm Final
#>   <int> <chr>   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>
#> 1     1 0       G            G       G    
#> 2     2 43      0            71      18   
#> 3     3 0       G            G       G    
#> 4     4 0       G            G       G    
#> 5     5 60      38           64      27   
#> 6     6 0       G            G       G
```

Your data

```r
grades <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:6),
  Quiz1 = c("0","0","0","0","60","0"),
  Quiz2 = c("G","G","G","G","38","G"),
  Quiz3 = c("G","43","G","G","G","G"),
  Midterm = c("G","71","G","G","64","G"),
  Final = c("G","18","G","G","27","G")
)
`
```